# Wordpress Customizer not allowing menu options

Tags: theme-customizer

I am having trouble with the Wordpress Customizer. I am trying to add a page to my menu and I am unable to select anything, as seen on the right hand side with the dropdown arrow buttons. [image: There is no option to select anything as there are no dropdown menu items when clicking on pages or custom links]
I am using the Astra theme and the issue remains even when using the standard Wordpress themes.

Comment: What do you mean "unable to select anything"? It's not clear from your screenshot.

Comment: As seen in the image, the tabs are there but when you click the arrow, nothing shows up. There should be at the very least, pages to add to the menu as they are on the website. Normally, when you click the tabs the pages that are on the website are shown so you can add them to the menu.